# How to Enable/Disable Ribbon Command officejs

Tags: office-js

We followed below reference regarding enable/diable ribbon command but still not clear with that.

1) We were able disable when add-in runs initially
2) But could not enable one ribbon command based on other command event.

**Kindly provide some examples**.

Tried below but not sure where to call method **enableButton**.

```
const enableButton = async () => {
    const button: Control = {id: "MyButton", enabled: true};
    const parentTab: Tab = {id: "OfficeAddinTab1", controls: [button]};
    const ribbonUpdater: RibbonUpdaterData = { tabs: [parentTab]};
    await Office.ribbon.requestUpdate(ribbonUpdater);
}
```

@Rick.. Sorry for missing reference. Also the one which you mentioned used as reference and below are our try and exception got. Kindly suggest.

**WORD AROUND TRIED:**

```
Office.onReady(async () => {
enableButton();
});
const enableButton = async () => {
var button = {id: "Menu", enabled: true};
var parentTab = {id: "Tab1", controls: [button]};
var ribbonUpdater = { tabs: [parentTab]};
await Office.ribbon.requestUpdate(ribbonUpdater);
}
```

**ISSUE :**

1) Uncaught (in promise) RichApi.Error: The API you are trying to use is not available. It may be available in a different scenario.
at new c (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/excel-web-16.00.js:24:293355)
at c.f.processRequestExecutorResponseMessage (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/excel-web-16.00.js:24:354008)
at https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/excel-web-16.00.js:24:352113

2) taskpane.js:14734 Uncaught (in promise) RichApi.Error: The API you are trying to use is not available. It may be available in a different scenario.
at new c (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/excel-web-16.00.js:24:293355)
at c.f.processRequestExecutorResponseMessage (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/excel-web-16.00.js:24:354008)
at https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/excel-web-16.00.js:24:352113

[image]

Comment: What is the "below reference"? Did you see this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/disable-add-in-commands#change-the-state-in-response-to-an-event

Comment: Hi Team, Any update please?

Comment: The API recently changed. You are using the latest version, but maybe your version of Office isn't quite new enough. What is your Office version? I have Office 365 2005, Build 12813 20000.

Comment: @Rick.. we are using Office365  2005 Build 12816 200006... anyway we are doing testing in Office Excel online only....should it work right?

Comment: In Excel Online, the API only works with the simplified ribbon turned on. Are you able to see the simplified ribbon?

Comment: Yes Rick. We always working on the simplified ribbon excel and the above mentioned issues were  caught in Crhome debugger tool with turning on simplified ribbon...Kindly review the implemented code and confirm if anything wrong in that...

Comment: Hi Rick,  If possible kindly share simple example with manifest configurations.

Comment: Are you using a Shared Runtime as described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/disable-add-in-commands ? Also,, here's a sample: https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP-OfficeAddins/tree/master/Samples/excel-shared-runtime-scenario with a manifest that uses the enable feature.

Comment: Thanks Rick. Will go through sample once and let you know if any issues....

Comment: Hi Rick...Now able to enable commands....Can you confirm whether this feature applicable for Menu control also?

Comment: Also it is working fine for single taskpane and not able to use share runtime for two taskpanes.... It will be better provide in above said scenario.... Thanks....

Comment: Hi I have attached screen shot that is getting opened downside arrow icon for every task pane click in ribbon command ....Can you provide any configuration need to correct in manifest file related with task pane....

Comment: Hi Rick,based on my another testing it seems due to enable/disable feature taskpane not working properly for many numbers...

Comment: @Rick.....Any update on this?

Comment: It seems that you are now having a different issue. Could you start a new Stack Overflow question?

Answer (score 1):

You must use a Shared Runtime as described in Enable and disable add-in commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/disable-add-in-commands). Here's a sample, [shared-runtime-scenario](https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP-OfficeAddins/tree/master/Samples/excel-shared-runtime-scenario), with a manifest that uses the enable feature.

Comment: Hi Rick, I have already been using the same sample which you provided earlier....the issue currently am facing is in attached screen shot when trying to play with multiple task-panes which are the required scenario... let me know if anything required.

Comment: Also sharing runtime between the task-panes are not working properly based on manifest configuration. For single task pane it can be implemented but the issue only with if add-in have more than one task panes..

Comment: This is a different issue. Please create a new Stack Overflow question.